# Cats.validate, what's the difference between ValidatedNel[+E,+A] and Validated[+E,+A]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm learning how to validate data using `Cats.Validate`.
I'm not sure what's the difference between `ValidatedNel[+E,+A]` and `Validated[+E,+A]`?
I know `ValidatedNel` is defined as:

`type ValidatedNel[+E, +A] = Validated[NonEmptyList[E], A]`

But anyway, what's the difference between `Validated[NonEmptyList[E], A]` and `Validated[+E,+A]`?
When it's better to use one or another? What do I have to take into account when deciding which to use?

Comment: Well you already said the difference, `ValidatedNel` is a `Validated` whose invalid case is always a `NonEmptyList` _(of something)_. Since the idea of `Validated` is to accumulate errors, then it makes sense to accumulate them on a collection, and since you know that if you have errors then you have at least one a non empty collection is a good idea. And since you know you are appending errors a collection with fast append is even better _(thus I prefer `ValidatedNec` which uses a `NonEmptyChain`)_. So really there is no difference is just a shorthand for  a common type.

Comment: BTW, with the inclusion of the `Parallel` typeclass then it is now better to use `Either` over `Validated` most of the time and use `parTraverse` instead. - `Validated` is still useful if you want to use it for its `Semigroup` rather than its `App locative`.

Comment: Thank you Luis. I've been reading more on the web, and now I see your point. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly mentioned already `ValidatedNel` is just type alias for `Validated`. The only difference is how you want to collect your validation errors.With `ValidateNel` errors will be collected in `NonEmptyList`, but if you would like for instance prove on type level you are going to have only unique errors you can define own `type ValidatedNes[+E, +A] = Validated[NonEmptySet[E], A]`.

Another words you can think about `ValidatedNel` as suggested default validation structure and `Validated` as more low-level structure for cases which `ValidatedNel` doesn't cover.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I see your point, thanks for your help!